# Python API ShaderNodeTexWood undefined

Tags: python, materials

I am running Blender 5.1. I used ShaderNodeTexWoodTexture as in the following line
wood_texture = wood_material.node_tree.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexWoodTexture")

I got a runtime error "ShaderNodeTexWoodTexture undefined""

Has the type changed? what should I replace it with?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I don't think this node was ever available to the shader editor. Maybe you're thinking of the texture node editor ?

Comment: @Gorgious. It may be available in the fictional Blender 5.1 version though! :^)

Comment: So what would be the right way if any to have the wood texture. Please help enlighten me